# python cloudinary replace image

Tags: python, cloudinary

In python I am doing the following:

```
returned = cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    url, use_filename = True,
    unique_filename = False,
    invalidate = True,
    overwrite = True)
```

But it doesn't seem to replace/overwrite the image.

Answer (score -1):

It usually takes a few minutes to an hour for the CDN cache to be invalidated. Also, you'll need to make sure your URLs follow the convention Cloudinary invalidates by. Alternatively, you can use 'version' component to receive the newest image each time.

For more information on both 'version' and 'invalidate' options: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520852-How-can-I-update-an-already-uploaded-image-

Comment: To avoid link rot, please edit your question to include the pertinent details from the link.